# How to add a dictionary as a column to a data frame in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to add a new column in a data frame from the result of a function that generates a sorted dictionary. But I can't get it working.

I'm using Python 3.6 and running it on Pycharm using a local spark session. I tried using ArrayType but that doesn't seem to fix it. The output column is null

```
def getDictionary(data):

    hour = ['8', '9', '10']
    score = [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
    res = dict(zip(hour, score))

    sorted_x = sorted(res.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=1)
    sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_x)

    first3pairs = {k: sorted_dict[k] for k in list(sorted_dict)[:3]}
    return first3pairs
```

```
get_res_udf = F.udf(getDictionary, ArrayType(StringType()))

data = data.withColumn('result', get_res_udf(data['probability']))
data.show(10, False)
```

**Error:**

```
+----------+-------------------------+------+
|loannumber|scoring_ts_utc           |result|
+----------+-------------------------+------+
|  11111111|2019-08-01 19:33:18.98721|null  |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
```

**Expected:**

```
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|loannumber|scoring_ts_utc           |result|
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  11111111|2019-08-01 19:33:18.98721|{'8': 0.15553969938314824, '10': 0.1135606782079484, '12': 0.10158022312738095, '14': 0.08433517313467825}  |
+----------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: change the `udf` return type to `MapType(StringType(), FloatType())` and let me know if that output is okay for you. Or if you want the string as  you've shown it (with double quotes instead of single) you can use `json.dumps` and return type of `StringType()`.

Comment: @pault - I started off doing it that way but the result was: `[8 -> 0.1555397, 12 -> 0.101580225, 14 -> 0.08433517, 10 -> 0.11356068]`

Comment: There is no dictionary datatype in spark. There is only `MapType`. What is your end goal?

Comment: Just to store that in that format. A list would work too. The json.dumps worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!!